# How to change the column data in sqlite database browser in android?

Tags: android

I need to change the data stored in my sqlite database. Actually I need to change the path of the image in one of the column.

**i.e in column 3 the data I stored as src="/image/first.png". But now I need to change the path to src="/Seperatefolder/first.png". Please help me how to do this?**

Will be thankful.....

Comment: Which sqlite database browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:-

```
1) In Eclipse change view to DDMS and click file explorer.
2) your database file is located at data->data->package name.
3) push the .db file to desktop.
4) open firefox browser.
5) open tools and click sqlite manager.
6) if you dont have sqlite manager. go to addons and type sqlite.
7) install it.
8) open the database in sqlite browser and change data in it.
```